# Explosive force exerted between two objects - one fixed and the other loose

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Suppose we have 2 objects next to each other - one fixed and the other is moveable.  What will happen if I put them close to each other and I release a force in the middle - like an explosion. Will the force exerted be equal on both the fixed one and the moving one?

[image: Example]

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A practical version of the system in your question is a rifle bolted to the Earth.
The rifle contains a bullet which is discharged by pulling a trigger.
To simplify matters even more I will assume that it is a compressed but massless spring which is going to eject the bullet from the rifle.

Initially the bullet and the rifle & Earth are at rest.

The trigger is pulled and a bullet is ejected from the rifle.

The force on the bullet due to one end of the spring is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force that end of the spring due to the bullet - this is Newton's third law in action.

The force on the rifle due to the other end of the spring is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force on the other end of the spring due to the rifle - again this is Newton's third law in action.

Since the spring is massless the force on one end of the spring due to the bullet is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force on the other end of the spring due to the rifle.

This in turn means that the force on the bullet due to one end of the spring is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force on the rifle due to the other end of the spring and this leads to the answer to your question.

The magnitude of the force on the loose object is equal to the magnitude of the force on the fixed object.

---

I want to amplify this a little by noting what happens to the "fixed" object which in this case is the rifle bolted to the Earth.

Because the initial momentum of the bullet, rifle and the Earth was zero, the momentum of the bullet will be equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the rifle & Earth - this is the law of conservation of momentum in action.

Because the Earth has a mass which is so much greater than that of the bullet the "recoil" of the rifle & Earth will not be noticeable in this case but you will recognise that this means that your "fixed" object  will move together with whatever it is attached to in the oppose direction to the direction of the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the local stress at the boundaries of the objects. Therefore the answer to your question is rather related to he way the stress/pressure is released by the explosion. Assuming it is released in a symmetric way, yes both bodies are subject to the same forces (at least in the beginning). After a while the object which can move is pushed away. Then there might be a stress/pressure asymmetry between your two surfaces.